# How to Handle multiple duplicate records in one column by populating the values in second column with same name?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, select, inner-join

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onYZG.png)

In the table , I have multiple records like of the movie name Adalat and the genre for 3 is different
and one is null. I want to populate the empty place with the Genre of Adalat that comes first from the 3.
How to do the same?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mliNI.png)
This query is giving me [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeaF6.png) result which is incorrect ? Please guide me

Comment: Welcome :-) Please do not post data as pictures. Please post sample data that we can work with. Makes it much easier to help you.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to decide what is the 'first' Genre. Here, I assume by year. Then write subquery to get this data.

Then left join to this subquery from your main table and if the genre is null, then use the genre from the subquery

Something like this...

Note: This is untested as you did not supply any useable data to work with  so there might be syntax errors but it should point you in the right direction.

```
SELECT 
    m.ID,
    m.[Name],
    m.MovieYear,
    ISNULL(m.Genre, dg.Genre) AS Genre
    FROM MoviesIndia m 
    LEFT JOIN ( -- get genre by name where row number is 1 (default genre)
                SELECT [Name], Genre as DefaultGenre 
                    FROM ( -- get row number for each genre per name
                            SELECT 
                                [Name], Genre, 
                                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [NAME] ORDER BY MovieYear) as rn
                                FROM MoviesIndia
                                WHERE Genre IS NOT NULL
                        ) r  WHERE r.rn = 1
              ) dg 
              ON m.[Name] = dg.[Name]
```

To understand how it works, run the inner most query first, then work your way out and it should be fairly easy to follow.

Comment: You're welcome. If this answered your question, please mark the answer as accepted (the check box to the left under the vote up/down buttons). This helps other users find answers to similar questions.